# Redirect using useNavigate with React-router-dom V6 not working after successfully logging in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router

I am trying to navigate to another page on my SPA after logging in using `navigate("/modules")` from react-router-dom. However, the desired redirect page is shown for a moment in the website URL before I am redirected to the page mentioned in my PublicRoute component (redirects to the `Welcome` page always).

I feel this is a result of initially starting on the login page (a publicRoutes page) and when login is successful,  since I am now on a 'forbidden' page, I am redirected to the default redirect instead of the desired redirect mentioned in the login workflow. I am stuck on how to fix this

Here is some code of my app code and my login workflow:

```
//main.jsx
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
<BrowserRouter>
  <AuthContextProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthContextProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
)

//App.jsx
function App() {

return (
<Routes>

  <Route path='/' element={<SharedLayout/>}>

    <Route element={<PrivateRoutes/>}>
      <Route path="/welcome" element={<PrivateHome/>}/>
      <Route path="/modules" element={<Modules/>}/>
    </Route>

    <Route element={<PublicRoutes/>}>
      <Route path="/" element={<PublicHome/>}/>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
      <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup/>}/>
    </Route>
  
  </Route>
</Routes>
)

 }
```

And the protected / public routes:

```
//PrivateRoutes.jsx
function PrivateRoutes ({children, ...rest}) {

const {user} = UserAuth()

if (user===undefined) return <Loading/>

return (
  user ? <Outlet/>: <Navigate to="/login"/>
)
}


//PublicRoutes.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Loading from '../components/Loading'
import { UserAuth } from './AuthContext'

function PublicRoutes ({children}) {
    
    const {user} = UserAuth()

    if (user===undefined) return <Loading/>

    return (
      user ? <Navigate to="/welcome"/> : <Outlet/>
    )
}


//Login.jsx
  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
try {
  await login(email, password)
  navigate("/modules")
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  setPassword("")
}
```

}

and my subscriber listener for user auth changes inside context provider (firebase)

```
//AuthContext.jsx
const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children})=> {
const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined) //undefined -> loading

const login = (email, password) => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
}

  useEffect(()=> {
   const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser)
   })

  return ()=> {
    unsubscribe()
  }
 }, [])

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, login}}>
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
) 

export const UserAuth = () => {
 return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Side note: The usual navigate snippet works in other cases without issue with my current code ,as far as I can tell, but just not when moving from a publicRoute to a privateRoute page, or vice versa...

Comment: We may need to see a more complete [mcve] to say what any issue is. Can you [edit] to include the complete component code, the router, the routes, the context provider code, etc?

Comment: added some more component code that hopefully helps clear up my code structure!

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything overtly an issue with the code you have. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem occurs during login. When  on the login page, pressing submit, I expect the user to be directed to "/modules" page after the async login code completes. However I notice the user is directed to the desired URL but just for a second and immediately the user is redirected to the page mentioned in the public routes (in this case "/welcome"). Feels like there is some sort of sync issue but I can't figure out how to avoid this double redirect. @DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be correct in that this is a effectively a "race condition" between successfully signing in with `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and the `onAuthStateChanged` listener updating the `user` state in the context. The issue is that the app is navigating to a protected route prior to the `user` state updating to allow the user through to the protected content.

What may work for you here would be to delay the navigation action to the *end* of the Javascript event queue to allow the `setUser` call to be processed first. Use a `setTimeout` callback to do this. Use as short of a delay as you need, even `0` is sufficient in most cases.

Example:

Login.jsx

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const handleLogin = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    await login(email, password);
    setTimeout(navigate, 0, "/modules");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    setPassword("");
  }
};
```

Comment: SetTimeout works perfectly for this.  Thank you!